# Datepicker trouble

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi i cant get this datepicker to work? can someone help me to get it to work, it dosent do anything when i click on it!

And it is from this site i'm trying to make their example.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/jasenhk/4g9u5/

HEAD:

```
<head>

<!--Bootstrap stylesheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--Bootstrap scripts-->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<!--Custom stylesheets-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<!--Custom scripts-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".date-picker").datepicker();

    $(".date-picker").on("change", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var val = $("label[for='" + id + "']").text();
        $("#msg").text(val + " changed");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

BODY:

```
<div class="controls">
    <div class="input-group">
    <label for="date-picker-3" class="input-group-addon btn">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </label>
    <input id="date-picker-3" type="text" class="date-picker form-control 
hasDatepicker">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Oh do you mean you can't get it working on your site?  Im going to guess that you have not included jQuery or some other library.

Comment: What is the problem? Any errors in console?

Comment: Include jQuery before bootstrap. And include jQuery UI file too

Comment: Looking good! When you load the page are you getting any prompt to allow scripts etc?

Comment: No i dosent get any errors, i have missed something and cannot figure out out what it is. @wunth have also tried adding Jquery before bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `hasDatepicker` class from your input. Also your HTML is malformed:

```
<input id="date-picker-3" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
```

And your jQuery script tag is also malformed:

```
<!--Custom scripts-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

And you're missing the jQuery UI:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle working example: http://jsfiddle.net/054xstp5/15/